# Localizar letras no meio do array com preg_grep

Tags: php, regex

Sou bem ruim pra fazer esse tipo de pesquisa e não tenho muita noção de como fazer, do modo que eu fiz consigo apenas localizar a palavra se escrita por inteira se estiver na sequência (do início ao fim).

Como posso fazer para localizar por apenas letras invés das palavras por inteiras, sendo elas localizadas em qualquer parte do sub array `names`?

```
<?php
    $find = 'as'; //para localizar o 'foo bar bas' no sub array names na quarta posição
    $directories = array (
        'names' => array(
            'hi',
            'hello pt.stackoverflow',
            'hello world',
            'foo bar bas',
        ),
        'dir' => array(
            'directory 1',
            'directory 2',
            'directory 3',
            'directory 4'
        ),
        'type' => array(
            'file',
            'folder',
            'file',
            'folder'
        )
    );
    $matches = preg_grep('/^'.$find.' (\w+)/i', $directories['names']);
    $keys = array_keys($matches);
    if(count($keys) != 0){
        echo count($keys) . ' resultados encontrados </br>';
        foreach($keys as $index) {
            echo 
                $directories['names'][$index] . ' | ' . 
                $directories['dir'][$index]  . ' | ' . 
                $directories['type'][$index] . '</br>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Sem resultados para a busca ' . $find . '</br>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre a regex que você usou: `'/^'.$find.' (\w+)/i'`. Como a variável `$find` é "as", o resultado final é `/^as (\w+)/i`.

As barras são os delimitadores da regex e não fazem parte da expressão propriamente dita.

Depois temos o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que significa "início da string". Em seguida temos as letras "as", seguidas de espaço, seguidas de `\w+`.

O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` corresponde a "letras, dígitos ou o caractere `_`", e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências".

Ou seja, a regex procura por strings que **comecem** com "as", seguido de um espaço, seguido de um ou mais `\w` (letras, dígitos ou `_`). E claramente a string que você está buscando (`'foo bar bas'`) não corresponde à expressão.

Se quer buscar "as" em qualquer parte da string, basta que a expressão seja `/as/`. No caso, basta fazer assim:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/'.$find.'/', $directories['names']);
```

Com isso, a string `'foo bar bas'` é encontrada, pois agora a regex procura por "as" em qualquer parte das strings (não somente no início), além de não obrigar que depois haja um espaço e outros caracteres.

---

No seu código você também usou a opção `i`, que [torna a regex *case insensitive*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Ou seja, se você fizer:

```
$find = 'as';
$matches = preg_grep('/'.$find.'/i', $directories['names']);
```

Serão encontradas strings que contenham "as", "AS", "aS" ou "As". Se você remover o `i`, serão encontradas somente strings que contenham "as".

---

E caso queira somente as strings que terminam em "as", pode usar o marcador `$` (final da string):

```
$matches = preg_grep('/'.$find.'$/i', $directories['names']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi da sua dúvida, a regex seria só o termo de busca:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/'.$find.'/', $directories['names']);
```